# Python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm fails using spacy 3.0.6

Tags: python

After downloading, it shows the following:

> en-core-web-sm==3.0.0) (2.0.1)
> Installing collected packages: en-core-web-sm
> Attempting uninstall: en-core-web-sm
> Found existing installation: en-core-web-sm 2.2.0
> Uninstalling en-core-web-sm-2.2.0:
> Successfully uninstalled en-core-web-sm-2.2.0
> Successfully installed en-core-web-sm-3.0.0
> ✔ Download and installation successful

but when I trying to run the code it shows again to again....
[after run the script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pp61o.png)
....

Comment: Pls dont link images. Copy the stacktracae and add it to your question

Comment: You have to restart your pc. After that it will be loaded.